# Rails devise not working for rails 3.2.1 on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I followed each and every single step for devise to work on my localhost as discussed under this tutorial - http://www.slideshare.net/wleeper/devise-and-rails  `upto page 8 of 22` and I was expecting the same user login form as mentioned on the page 8 but apart from this, i am getting this error-

If i keep the comments as it is on routes.rb file,

**# match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'**

then this message flags -

[image: Error 1]

And when i uncomment this line it show this error-

[image: Error 2]

Have very less idea about rails, as I am from PHP background, but still trying some practical tests before theory, so let me know what exactly im doing wrong.

My routes.rb file -

```
Prjmgt::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'
    root :to => 'home#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
   match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Just run a `rake routes` command and find this -

[image: rake routes]

Comment: please show your routes rb

Comment: @Lichtamberg just pasted and let me know if you need anything other to investigate..currently on a learning mode..need support from you people over Rails tuts :)

Comment: @Lichtamberg plese find my comments below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the wrong url.. you should try it with

```
http://application/users/login
```

you dont have the right root url like

```
root :to => redirect("/users/login")
```

Comment: I tried with these URLs but still not working :(  http://localhost:3000/users/new & http://localhost:3000/users/  added my rake routes screenshot as well

Comment: then try it with localhost:3000/login

Comment: or with localhost:3000/register

Comment: even this is not working too..let me know what other files i can look into

Comment: http://localhost:3000/register/index & http://localhost:3000/register/  not working :(

Comment: still no luck..seriously need some help..as rails turning out to be little complex from this part :(

Comment: @Litchtamberg one fix..i just checked my application.rb file and assets was mis spelled so on correcting this gone, but now i m getting precompile error

Comment: config.assets.initialize on precompile - false this line in same file also sounds scary to me..if it is correct ??

Comment: please post your application.rb file