# How to navigate and read URL in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake

This part of question is a part of this question [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427776/rails-devise-not-working-for-rails-3-2-1-on-localhost)

After running the `rake routes` command and understanding the taxonomy of errors I finally came up with this window, but being a newbie in ROR I am not able to track down the URL to have the effects.

This is the outcome and i believe its error free as well -

[image: Correct]

However I tried these URLs but none is working :(

```
http://localhost:3000/
http://localhost:3000/users
http://localhost:3000/user
```

Routes.rb file --

```
Prjmgt::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'
    root :to => 'home#index'


  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
   match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Comment: The answer to your previous question should give you all the information you need

Comment: @Charles I dont think so(may be i am wrong in the case) as the prevoius one is for errors ..while this one is for after correcting those errors and need to check if things are correct or not with the taxonomy to read Rails structure from the screenshot provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root URL should be working fine.

However, note that

```
/user
```

doesn't exist anywhere in your routes and that

```
/users
```

is only accessible through a post request. In devise, this is used to submit a form using the post method to create a new user.

Simply opening a url in your browser means using a get request, and there is no get route set up for `/users`.

Try out `/users/sign_up` in your browser, it should lead you to devise's sign up page.

I suggest your read into the [rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: even http://localhost:3000/ is throwing error in this case :(  Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/"

Comment: Do you have something like `root to: "home#index"` in your routes.rb? Can you please show us the contents of your routes.rb file?

Comment: @Charles..just added plz  chk

Comment: Have you made sure to have a home controller, an index method inside it and a home/index.html.erb view?

Comment: And if that still doesn't work, all I can think of is restarting your server (routes changes are only effective once your restart the server). Please let me know how you're progressing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definition for `http://localhost:3000/`, which is the root directory. and `http://localhost:3000/user` doesn't make any sense at all, because controllers are always plural.

`http://localhost:3000/users` would normally be ok for a controller, but it seems like you are using some user management thing, so it doesn't accept get requests.

try: `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up` or `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`

Comment: He is using a "user management thing" called [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) (which is pretty awesome by the way)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your previous question, you haven't set up /users yet. Try adding

```
resources :users
```

to your routes.rb.

As for the Devise routes try visiting http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in]

**EDIT:**

Also this line,

```
/:controller/:action/:id
```

is not literal.

It's just an example of the match method. It should look something like

```
match "/users/:id" => "users#show"
```

This matches /users/1 to the show method in your UsersController.

Comment: Not needed. In his routes.rb file there will be something like `devise_for :users`, which sets up all needed routes.

Comment: That only sets up the devise routes. It doesn't set up the basic CRUD routes. That's why it's not showing up in his rake routes.